# Highcharts: create multiple series using JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, spline

I am trying to create a `line, spline` chart using JSON data. I want multiple series but I am confused on how to do that. Right now I am able to create one with one series but this one doesn't look right either. Plus I don't see the legend either. Please help on how I can fix this. Right now I only have the code for `starts`. I also want to `completes` to my chart. I want the legends to say `start` and `complete`

JSON Data:

```
[
{
    "date": "2019-07-07",
    "starts": 42,
    "completes": 142
},
{
    "date": "2019-07-08",
    "starts": 2,
    "completes": 90
},
{
    "date": "2019-07-09",
    "starts": 28,
    "completes": 175
}
]
```

My Code:

```
<div id="container"></div>

let theAPI = `the json file`

$.getJSON(theAPI, result => {
    let main_chart_data = [];

    result.forEach((d, i) => {
        let date_chart = new Date(d.date);
        main_chart_data.push([date_chart, d.starts, ]);
    });

    let main_chart_options = buildChart({
        chart_type: 'spline',
        height: 265
    });
    main_chart_options.legend.enabled = false;
    main_chart_options.lang = {
        'noData': 'There is currently no data available.'
    };
    main_chart_options.series = [{
        data: main_chart_data
    }];

    main_chart_options.tooltip = {
        formatter: function() {
            let tooltip = `
      <span style="font-weight:500;">${moment(this.x).format('MMM DD - ha')}</span>
      <br />
      <span>${addCommas(this.y)}</span>
    `;
            return tooltip;
        },
        useHTML: true
    }

    new Highcharts.chart('container', main_chart_options);

    let total_pvs = result.reduce((a, c) => {
        return a += c.starts;
    }, 0);

})
```

This is my result now:

[Spline - Highchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRL5L.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by splitting the JSON data into two separate series to look like that:

```
[{
  "name": "starts",
  "data": [{
    "x": 1562457600000, // date in milliseconds
    "y": 42
  }, {
    "x": 1562544000000,
    "y": 2
  }, {
    "x": 1562630400000,
    "y": 28
  }]
}, {
  "name": "completes",
  "data": [{
    "x": 1562457600000,
    "y": 142
  }, {
    "x": 1562544000000,
    "y": 90
  }, {
    "x": 1562630400000,
    "y": 175
  }]
}]
```

**Check this demo to see how you can make it:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tjLvh89b/

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked! Is there anyway to group this data by month as well?

Comment: That is when I have my JSON set up like `[
    {
        "month": 6,
        "year": 2019,
        "starts": 21278998,
        "completes": 9309458
    },
    {
        "month": 7,
        "year": 2019,
        "starts": 38850115,
        "completes": 17790105
    }
]`

Comment: I answered you there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57295753/highcharts-create-multiple-series-grouped-my-month-and-year-using-json-data/57303499#57303499

Comment: Hi Wojciech, I used your example. I had a quick question about something. Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rprak0605/kc9g5vrh/ . I want to create a new series, a `series5`. I want series5 to be able to use `elem.starts` from json1 and divide it by `elem.x` from json2. I want `series5` to be `x: +new Date(elem.date), y: elem.starts/elem.x`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/09nx3yot/

Comment: Thank you for all your help but I was hoping you can help me with an issue I am facing with column charts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57504782/fix-space-between-columns-and-align-labels-on-highcharts

Comment: Hi Wojciech, can you please help with an issue I am facing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442778/why-am-i-getting-gaps-in-my-areaspline-highcharts

Comment: is there any way to do http://jsfiddle.net/rprak0605/31d8jxzu/3/ using json data and having multiple series?