# Highcharts: create multiple series grouped my month and year using JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, spline

I am trying to create a line, spline chart using JSON data. I want multiple series but I am confused on how to do that. Right now I am able to create the multiple series when the date is in `2019-07-06` format. I also have a JSON that has a column for the month and a column for the year Please help on how I can fix this. Right now I only have the code for group by day.

JSON Data:

```
[ 
 { "month": 6, 
   "year": 2019, 
   "starts": 21278998, 
   "completes": 9309458 
 }, 
 { "month": 7, 
   "year": 2019, 
   "starts": 38850115, 
   "completes": 17790105 
 } 
]
```

I used the solution for the date format `2019-07-06` provided in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tjLvh89b/

Please help with how I can create a chart for the `Month, Year` on the `x-Axis`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it simply by creating a Date object using different parameters.

Instead of the string date parameter `new Date('2019-07-07')` use year and month as separate parameters like that: `new Date(2019, 7)`.

**Code:**

```
var json = [{
  month: 6,
  year: 2019,
  starts: 21278998,
  completes: 9309458
}, {
  month: 7,
  year: 2019,
  starts: 38850115,
  completes: 17790105
}];

var series1 = {
    name: 'starts',
    data: []
  },
  series2 = {
    name: 'completes',
    data: []
  };

json.forEach(elem => {
  series1.data.push({
    x: +new Date(elem.year, elem.month),
    y: elem.starts
  });

  series2.data.push({
    x: +new Date(elem.year, elem.month),
    y: elem.completes
  });
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: [
    series1,
    series2
  ]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xtefuLsp/1/

**Date object reference:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Hi, can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57601555/highcharts-areaspline-not-getting-the-default-color-for-chart

Comment: I answered you there.

Comment: Can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61650530/highcharts-stacked-column-chart-from-json-not-charting-correct-values

Comment: Can you please help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897720/create-multiple-pie-highcharts-for-multiple-series