# Fix space between columns and align labels on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, column-chart

I am creating a column chart but I see too much space between the columns and I want to reduce the space between them. The labels on the xAxis are also not aligning.

This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3atxr4c/1/.

I added `pointPadding`, `borderWidth` and `groupPadding`. None of these are working.

Is there a way for me to reduce space between the columns?

Also all the values show up on my webpage (with navigation working) but are not on the fiddle so thats why I have a large div.

I want to be able to adjust the distance the columns and align the labels on the xAxis for them. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` options won't work as long as the `pointWidth` is set, which takes precedence. As for the xAxis' labels, they are aligned correctly because they are in the center of all points of a specific category. You can't see them as they have 0 values. You can either remove 0's points or set `grouping` property to false.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointWidth
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping

Examples:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zsnju2xm/ - using `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` with all points visible
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kzrunfv0/ - using `grouping`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you please also take take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512471/legends-not-matching-columns-ticks-on-xaxis-in-highcharts? I dont know what I am doing wrong

Comment: this bar char doesn't hid when legend is clicked